# Jwt strategy with ES256k algorithm (not supported ?)

Tags: nestjs

I have an authentication microservice which sign a jwt using ES256k algorithm, when I try to use this token to call an API from a separate microservice with jwt strategy/guard, it doesn't work cause I guess ES256k is not a supported algorithm.
So is there a way to customize the verification to use a service or a function to verify tokens in a certain way? Or I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you most likely use some provider like Auth0 or Cognito or OneLogin
these guys use sets of JWT to support multiple accounts, this is called JWKS

If my guess is correct your best choice is jwks-rsa library by Auth0
you can check a [list of supported algorithms here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa/blob/4e221406c256d2b34ced4e11498fa85ab3cd4a23/src/integrations/config.js)

and as your question has label nestjs, you can try to use my [boilerplate](https://github.com/GemunIon/nestjs-auth/tree/master/apps/jwks-rest)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, but I can't find an example of a public key set in the JWKS format for ES256K algorithm because If I'm not talking nonsense, I have to set that by myself as I'm creating the jwt with jsontokens [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsontokens) and verifying it using jwks-rsa library by Auth0, right?

Comment: So, I tried this JWKS format `{ "keys": [ { "kid": "30149", "kty": "EC-HSM", "crv": "SECP256K1", "x": "f4c395c51b46e9a4c2124fec6cfe1eac749167461ee7c3cf3b1895f2cbbddc19", "y": "5f0ec9748979d29ce4b96d03d494c3712e845550f65e0379c6daff8dc6114306" } ] }`, but it didn't work, I'm not sure about it though. For the x and y Coordinates I just split my ethereum publickey without the 0x or 04 prefix. For the nestjs JwtStrategy I just set `algorithms: ['ES256K']`. I had the following error `cb is not a function at secretProvider (at jwks-rsa) at Object.module.exports [as verify] (jsonwebtoken/verify.js)`.

Comment: oh you are using it with ethereum. not sure then but may be https://github.com/decentralized-identity/did-jwt will help you

Comment: you have a very interesting usecase nest+ethereum+jwt. can you please elaborate on how are you going to use this? I might try to write the code for you

Comment: I'll appreciate that! So, I have an entity (e.g university) which has an ethereum key pair and a unique ID on blockchain. Authentication microservice (nestjs) which sign a jwt (e.g. contains the student's info) using ES256k algorithm and the entity's ethereum private key with jsontokens [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsontokens). I'm trying to use the jwt to call an API (e.g to get student's exam mark) from a separate microservice (nestjs).

Comment: But I couldn't verify the token at the jwt strategy/guard level as it uses a different lib jsonwebtoken [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) which does not support ES256K algorithm. If I could use the jwks-rsa library and find the right public key set in the JWKS format for ES256K algorithm, then I can use the entity's unique ID as the kid to fetch the entity's public key from the JWKS endpoint. I hope it's more clear now !

Comment: A simplified workflow https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6NW4.png

Comment: it appears I do not need to write the code
here is already a complete solution with tests
https://github.com/civicteam/node-jsonwebtoken/tree/CIV-2498_use_crypto_manager_for_all_ec
Be caution this is a branch of the fork. so you fork the fork, switch to the branch and publish this code as @oumaima/jsonwebtoken then you can install it into your project like this `npm install --save-dev  jsonwebtoken@npm:@oumaima/jsonwebtoken` to override the original jsonwebtoken package with your code but preserve all names

Comment: But even this fork doesn't support ES256K algorithm, take a look at supported algorithms [link](https://github.com/civicteam/node-jsonwebtoken/tree/CIV-2498_use_crypto_manager_for_all_ec#algorithms-supported).  ES256K is different than ES256.

Comment: [it does](https://github.com/civicteam/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/f9ba00285d4055af2ebd1c2489e5fd272c5ccd1d/sign.js#L14)

Comment: Ah ok, it was not listed among the supported algorithms. I'll give it a try and let you know if it works. I really appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Could you, please, take a look at the fork I made https://github.com/MHADHBIOumaima/node-jsonwebtoken . Even with this fork I have to edit the jwsVerifyWithCryptoModule and jwsSignWithCryptoModule functions as the current implementation assume that you use something like sjcl to generate keys with sign and verify functions (that's not the case for ethereum keys). I didn't test the sign function, though. If you can test it, I'll appreciate that!